# To find the greatest integer value in hadoop using (java programming)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have started working in hadoop recently and I have just learned some basic theoretical knowledge about it. I am trying to solve a task where the input shall be be given in a text file, for example input.txt (1 10 37 5 4 98 100 etc)

I need to find the largest integer in the given inputs (ie. integer type). I am trying to pass the inputs in the arraylist, so that I can compare the first integer with the rest of all the integers (using for-loop).

1)Is it possible to find the solution in this way? if yes, I could not create an arraylist here in hadoop and need some tips :-)

2)Can we print only 'key' instead of key-value pairs? If so please help me. I tried to code in reduce function for not printing it but I am getting some errors.

Please guide me with some tips by which I can move forward. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you shall better have a single reducer.

In order to ensure that all the numbers get to the same reducer, you have to do 2 things:

1. Emit same key for all the input values in the mapper
2. Set reduce tasks to zero.

You `map()` method may look something like following:

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          context.write(new Text("MyAwesomeKey"), key); // assuming that your number is being read in the key
           }
```

In your `Reduce` class, have a property `max`, something like:
`Long max`

And the `reduce()` method may look something like following:

```
@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          context.write(new Text("MyAwesomeKey"), key); // assuming that your number is being read in the key
           }
```

Then override the `run()` too as we override `reduce()` :

```
 public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKey()) {
      reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
    }
    context.write(new LongWritable(max),new Text("")); // write the max value
    cleanup(context);
  }
```

To set reduce tasks to one, do the following in your job's `run()`, note that this is different from the above described `run()`:

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

**Note:** All above code follows the new *mapreduce* API and I believe that using old *mapred* API we will not be able to have a single point of hook after the reducer has done it's job, as we are able to do by overriding the `run()` of Reducer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. I will work on it and i will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your map step, you could map all the numbers to a single key.  Then in your reduce step, you can just take the max.  The reduce step will be passed an iterable collection of values for a given key -- no need to create your own ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. I will work on it and i will let you know. Thank you.